# Commutation $[x,p]=i\hbar$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

if we have position operator x and momentum operator p as follows:

$$ \hat x = x \space ; \space \hat p = - i \hbar {∂ \over ∂x} \space $$

How do we show the commutator is:

$$ [\hat x, \hat p] = i \hbar$$

I am stuck at:

$$ [\hat x, \hat p] = x \space (-i \hbar {∂ \over ∂x}) - (-i \hbar {∂ \over ∂x}) \space x = i \hbar \left ( {∂x \over ∂x} - x \space {∂ \over ∂x} \right ) $$

To my untrained eye it seems we must have the following (how come?):

$$ 1 - x \space {∂ \over ∂x} = 1 \implies x \space{∂ \over ∂x} = 0 $$

Comment: First term just multiplies, the second term: use Leibnitz's rule, subtract the two and Bob's you're uncle! They're operators on smooth functions, so give them something to eat, say $f(x)$, then work out $x d_x f(x) - d_x(x\,f(x))$ ....

Comment: For notation's sake should (∂x/∂x) in the third equation have been (∂/∂x)x so when I give it something to eat it derives xf(x) not just x?

Comment: No, it should be $x\,\partial/\partial x$, an operator with the effect $f(x)\mapsto x\,\partial f(x)/\partial x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds as though you're still getting a grip on what an operator is in QM. Read that idea literally: they're operators on smooth functions, so give them something to eat! $\hat{x}$ takes a smooth function $f(x)$ and sends it to $x\,f(x)$. So now, work out what, say, the operators $f(x)\mapsto x\,f(x)$ and $f(x)\mapsto \mathrm{d}_x f(x)$ do when you form their commutator. The first term $\hat{x}\,\hat{p}$ is a chain of two steps: $\hat{p}$ acts first, then $\hat{x}$. So we have the chain of transformations $f(x) \mapsto \mathrm{d}_x f(x) \mapsto x\,\mathrm{d}_x f(x)$. Do the same with the second term, subtract them and the commutator works out to $f(x)\mapsto x\,\mathrm{d}_x f(x) - \mathrm{d}_x (x\,f(x))$.

Now I've not quite done your problem, but it's the same idea. Add in the scaling constants in $\hat{p}$ and expand the commutator using Leibnitz's rule. You should then get it!

Comment: I am indeed just getting a grip. Thankyou!

Comment: @ben Great. I was a little wary of assumptions, but it's great to be of help. You need to practice with this kind of stuff to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add wavefuction:
$[\hat{x}, \hat{p}]\ \psi = x (- i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}) \psi -  (- i \hbar \frac{\partial}{ \partial x}) x\psi = i\hbar \psi  $ and thefore 
$[\hat{x}, \hat{p}]\ = i\hbar $.